# whatsapp неверный номер телефона selenium

Tags: python, selenium, whatsapp

В общем делаю рассылку на whatsapp с помощью selenium на Python. Пользуюсь этим около 2-х месяцев, но сегодня утром начались странности. Отправляет несколько сообщений, а потом начинает писать, что не верный номер телефона. Хотя такого быть не может. Те номера, на которые уже отправлялось сегодня он открывает нормально, а на другие пишет о неверном номере. Если очистить кеш - то нормально, может открыть и отправить сообщение как и должно, но это ближайшие ~15 номеров, ну а дальше снова этот хоровод. Единственное что есть так это в консоли высвечивается: "3476:12008:1116/133241.458:ERROR:interface_endpoint_client.cc(690)] Message 3 rejected by interface blink.mojom.Widget"
Оно возникает перед тем, как начинается эта свистопляска с неверным номером, но что это я так и не понял, как и не понял имеет ли оно отношение к моей проблеме. Прошу просто дать понимание в какой стороне вообще проблема. Из моих догадок

1. вотс из-за большого кол-ва отправленных сообщений за сутки решил ограничить(но странно, что после удаления кеша дает находить номера)
2. происходит какой-то конфликт кеша(часто переходы с разных whatапов, а номера куда отправляется сообщения могут совпадать, ну и я делаю это но созданном профиле Гугла, чтобы постоянно не носить телефоны к монитору)
3. У вотса свои тех работы, и завтра все будет норм(надеюсь и верю в это)
4. Виноваты звезды

Comment: Такие же проблемы массовые начались с 17 ноя с использованием whatsapp web и ссылок типа wa.me/number, в приложении для Windows пока работает нормально.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

столкнулся с такими же проблемами несколько дней назад. писал в поддержку whatsapp, вот что ответили: We are sorry to hear there is an ongoing issue with WhatsApp. This issue has been escalated to the appropriate parties and we are working to get this fixed. Thank you for your patience.